# Proving a function (provided as an algorithm) is bijective.

Tags: proof-writing, network

Suppose one has an algorithm which takes an object to produce another. Specifically in my case taking a network (graph) and producing another network through a number of non-trivial processes, i.e., we have a function $f: G_1 \to G_2$ where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the sets of the different graphs with $G_1 \cap G_2 = \emptyset$.

How can one prove (if possible) that $f$ is bijective? Is it simply sufficient to provide an inverse algorithm? The steps of the algorithm are difficult to formalise mathematically which is where the standard approach of showing $f$ is 1-1 and onto breaks down.

Comment: Find an inverse algorithm. Show that every element, when passed through the algorithm and then back via the inverse, returns to the same element. Further, show that every term in the range can be brought back by applying the inverse, and then the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the domain of your algorithm $f$ is a clear cut set $G_1$, and that $f$ produces for each $x\in G_1$ an element $f(x)\in{\cal G}$, whereby ${\cal G}$ is a large set of objects having certain properties. This $f$ is then a surjective map of $G_1$ onto the set $G_2:=f(G_1) \subset{\cal G}$. If you can prove that $f$ is also injective, i.e., that $x\ne y$ implies $f(x)\ne f(y)$, then $f$, considered as a map $f:\>G_1\to G_2$, is automatically bijective, and it is not necessary to present an explicit inverse.

If, however, $G_2$ is given in advance independently of $f$, and you only know that $f(x)\in G_2$ for any $x\in G_1$ then you have to prove the surjectivity of $f$ as well. This means that you have to show that you can find for each $y\in G_2$ an $x\in G_1$ with $f(x)=y$.

An important example at hand is the Laplace transform ${\cal L}$: It is defined for functions $f:\>{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}\to{\mathbb C}$ which increase at most exponentially with $t$. Nobody cares about the exact range, let alone image set, and there is no useful "inversion formula", but the fact that this ${\cal L}$ can be proven to be injective is absolutely central to the Laplace-transform-calculus.